# Alexandrov-Fenchel theorem for Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $E,M$ be two convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the Alexandrov-Fenchel theorem states that the coefficients $V_j(E,M)$ in
$$\operatorname{Vol}(xE+yM)=\sum_j {n\choose j} V_j(E,M)x^{n-j}y^j$$ satisfy $V_j(E,M)^2\geq V_{j-1}(E,M)V_{j+1}(E,M)$.

Is there a version of this for Riemannian manifolds? That if $E,M$ are subsets of a Riemannian manifold, then the same relation holds? Any references would be great.

Comment: In an arbitrary riemannian manifold, it is not clear what a linear combination x*E* + y*M* of two subsets *E*, *M* means. Maybe you want to restrict your question to cases where that makes sense.

Comment: @DanielAsimov  Perhaps one possible  sense could be the following: We change the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  compute the volum wrt the new metric. The  convexity can have two interpretation: wrt the  straight lines or  wrt the  geodesics of  metrics. Is it a reasonable sense for  consideration of the generalized Fenchel theorem?